# Failing string replacement in xargs command

Tags: linux, scripting, find, sed, xargs

I am trying to automatically create symlinks to directories and to replace a certain text string (foo) of the original name in the link name (bar). The name of the target directories may contain spaces (e.g. "foo with whitespace").

This is a minimal example:

```
> ls -Q

"foo"
"foo with whitespace"
```

I am trying the following command (using xargs' -p option to debug/check the result before its execution):

`` find . -iname "*foo*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' -p ln -s {} `echo {} | sed -e s#foo#bar#g ``

My desired outcome is this:

```
ln -s 'foo with whitespace' 'bar with whitespace'
ln -s 'foo' 'bar'
```

However the string replacement fails. The actual output looks like this:

```
ln -s './foo with whitespace' './foo with whitespace'?...
ln -s ./foo ./foo?...
```

If I use constant strings instead of {}, the string replacement works as intended:

`` find . -iname "*foo*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' -p ln -s {} `echo "foo" | sed -e s#foo#bar#g` ``

```
ln -s './foo with whitespace' bar?...
ln -s ./foo bar?...
```

What's my mistake and how do I fix the command invocation?

Edit: [Tilman Schmidt's solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/1100452/failing-string-replacement-in-xargs-command/1100455#1100455) works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command substitution

```
`echo {} | sed -e s#foo#bar#g`
```

is performed only once, *before* the pipeline composed of the `find` and `xargs` commands is run.
So `sed` gets the string `{}` as input and, not finding `foo`, outputs it unchanged.
*Then* the shell runs the resulting command line

```
find . -iname "*foo*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' -p ln -s {} {}
```

So command substitution is the wrong tool here.
Try something like

```
find . -iname "*foo*" -print | while read f; do ln -s "$f" "${f//foo/bar}"; done
```

(untested) instead.
Note that this won't work if you have filenames containing newlines.